# Angular Module Federation | Shell and Remote in Same App

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

Can an application act as a shell and remote and call it's own mfe?

part of webpack.config

```
const federatedModules = withModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'mfe',
    exposes: {
        './DownloadModule': './src/app/feature-modules/download/download.module.ts',
    },
    remotes:{
        "mfe": "https://local.app/remoteEntry.js"
    },
    shared: {
        ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', eager: true })
    }
});
```

When I try this I get error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')` from bootstrap.ts